# Jenkins - How to Hide source file contents with Warnings Next Generation Plugin

Tags: jenkins

Currently Warnings Next Generation Plugin is showing contents of entire sourcefiles whenever it finds a warning, I want just the warning snippet lines to be displayed in jenkins UI instead of complete source file, I tried exploring plugin but didn't found any option to do that.

Comment: [JENKINS-61038](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-61038)